# RequireJS and Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, requirejs

I currently using `javascript` and `knockout` for a learning site. I am trying to use typescript now.

In the old world, I had:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout.validation.js"></script>
```

That was in my layout page (Using an Asp.Net MVC application)

I am trying to use the MVC bundle thing. So my Bundle config has:

```
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/knockout").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/knockout-3.4.0.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/loadingModal").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/jquery.loadingModal.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/toastr").Include(
                       "~/Scripts/toastr.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/fileStyle").Include(
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css",
                      "~/Content/animate.css",
                      "~/Content/toastr.min.css",
                      "~/Content/jquery.loadingModal.min.css"));
```

That's all the js files I use, and my css files. And I have removed all my old style reference from my layout.

And in my layout, at the top, I just have:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/loadingModal")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/toastr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fileStyle")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

That seems to work. My knockout (old javascript version) is working fine.

I have created my first ts file, and am going to port the code to typescript. But I am stuck early.

My ts file has:

import ko = require('knockout');

As I want intellisense and all that in my ts files.

However, I get the error:

> Cannot find module 'knockout'

How do I get my ts file to 'know' about knockout? I have missed something somewhere, I think.

Comment: Have you tried typescript.definitelytyped library for knockout?? You can get it from nuget....

Comment: I downloaded it - but not sure how to reference it.

Comment: See if this could help you out - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/knockout.html...

Comment: which version of VS are you on? AFAIK, typescript is shipped by default with VS2015..